# Why is Asp.net Core using a lot of Extension Methods?

Tags: asp.net-core

Extension Methods are actually static methods. Does Asp.net core encourage to use static methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework uses extension methods to *extend* functionality. It allows for a modular system where components are registered using extension methods on low-level ASP.NET Core types. They are mainly used to configure [application startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup).

Sometimes utility methods for certain types are implemented as extension methods as well, rather than begin implemented in the type itself. This keeps the types clean and allows you to 'hide' advanced methods in a separate namespace.

ASP.NET Core actually discourages usage of statics by utilizing [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) as a first-class citizen. For example, there is no static `HttpContext.Current`  anymore. Instead, you can get a hold of the current HTTP context by injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` into your services.

Comment: These methods are a pain to unit test, I really wish they would put interfaces on all their classes and not use static or extension methods

Comment: Generally you shouldn't test these 'infrastructure' methods.

Comment: I'm not trying to test them, I'm trying to mock them out with Moq but I can't because they are static or non-overridable